# kubeflow deploy gcp endpoints controller fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubeflow

I am trying to deploy kubeflow on gcp using official guidelines https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/distributions/gke/deploy/deploy-cli/

I tried three times but it seems there is a problem with endpoints controller. When checked by: kubectl -n kubeflow get all

All pods are running except the

```
    NAME                                                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/admission-webhook-deployment-667bd68d94                1/1     Running            
pod/cache-deployer-deployment-75ccdc98b4                   2/2     Running            
pod/cache-server-56f78bf64b                                2/2     Running            
pod/centraldashboard-5fdbd9b744                            1/1     Running            
pod/cloud-endpoints-controller-5f7dbc6fc8                  0/1     ImagePullBackOff
```

Pod desciption says that it failed to resolve reference "gcr.io/cloud-solutions-group/cloud-endpoints-controller:0.2.1": unexpected status code [manifests 0.2.1]: 403 Forbidden

I am new to kubeflow but despite retrying this three times it always results in the same issue.

Comment: You should be able to browse `https://gcr.io/cloud-solutions-group/cloud-endpoints-controller:0.2.1` but the image does not appear to exist. That's one problem.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: v1.4.0, but I think it affects other versions too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clone the repo and build the image yourself and push it to your container registry.
This is one workaround to fix this until the official image is back.

```
git clone https://github.com/jlewi/cloud-endpoints-controller.git
cd cloud-endpoints-controller
git checkout 0.2.1
docker build . -t <YOUR DOCKER REGISTRY>/cloud-endpoints-controller:0.2.1
docker push <YOUR DOCKER REGISTRY>/cloud-endpoints-controller:0.2.1
```

And this use the new image in your pod spec.

Answer (score 1):

Urgent release is made: https://github.com/kubeflow/gcp-blueprints/releases/tag/v1.4.1, you can now use v1.4.1 tag for deployment.

---- original -----

Thank you for posting this issue! I have posted a mitigation solution here in https://github.com/kubeflow/gcp-blueprints/issues/343#issuecomment-1028488756. I am planning to fix this issue in the coming release.